# Pub-Sub implementation for Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, publish-subscribe

Have been looking for something similar to **IEventAggregator** in WPF-Prism framework.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33958805/is-there-an-event-pub-sub-framework-for-angular) is somewhat the same question in my mind, except that looking for a solution in Angular 5.

Couldn't find a simple solution so far. Had to create one myself using **typescript generics**, **angular dependency injection** using services and **"rxjs/Subject"**.

It is mostly inspired by [this](http://jasonwatmore.com/post/2016/12/01/angular-2-communicating-between-components-with-observable-subject) post.

A service named `EventService` is created and registered as a dependency in the `AppModule`. Since it is added in the `NgModule.providers` list of `AppModule`, it can be resolved as a dependency in any component.

EventService:

```
/**
 * For inter component communication throughout application.
 * Use dependency injection to raise an event with payload.
 * NOTE: All subscriptions to be unsubscribed at ngOnDestroy() method of subscribing component
 */
@Injectable()
export class EventService {

    private someDataChangeEvent: IEvent<string> = new Event<string>();

    constructor() { }

    public get someDataChange(): IEvent<string> {
        return this.userImageChangeEvent;
    }

}
```

where IEvent and Event is:

```
import { Subscription } from "rxjs";
import { Subject } from "rxjs/Subject";

export interface IEvent<T> {

    /**
     * Method which will signal the subscribers.
     * @param payload 
     */
    publish(payload: T): void,

    /**
     * Registers the payload receiving function.
     * NOTE: Subscribing component should handle the subscription disposal on ngOnDestroy method.
     * @param callback: callback function 
     */
    subscribe(callback: (payload: T) => void): Subscription
}

export class Event<T> implements IEvent<T> {

    private subject = new Subject<any>();

    constructor() { }

    public publish(payload: T): void {
        // Notify subscribers.
        this.subject.next(payload);
    }

    public subscribe(callback: (payload: T) => void): Subscription {
        // Create a subscription with the passed callback
        let subscription = this.subject.asObservable().subscribe(callback);
        return subscription;
    }
}
```

At the publishing component

1.Constructor - resolve dependency:

```
constructor(
  private readonly _eventService: EventService
) { }
```

2. Publish event when the data changes. Say, httpClient get complete or drop down item change or a button click. `payload` is the data you are sending to the subscribing component.

   ```
   self._eventService.someDataChange.publish(payload);
   ```

Now, at the subscribing component/s

1. Implement OnInit and OnDestroy
2. Constructor - resolve the dependency, same as above
3. In the ngOnInit method, subscribe event
4. In the ngOnDestroy unsubscribe subscription.

   ```
   export class SomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {

     constructor(
       private readonly _eventService: EventService
     ) { }

     private eventSubscription: Subscription = null;

     ngOnInit() {
       this.eventSubscription = this._eventService.someDataChange.subscribe((payload) => {
         // Do something with payload
       });
     }

     ngOnDestroy() {
       this.eventSubscription.unsubscribe();
     }
   }
   ```

I can define as many different events as application needs and multiple components can subscribe to these events. But all these subscriptions I need to carefully dispose of at the ngOnDestroy method.

Is there a way to avoid it? Is there a way to automatically delete the subscription, on the component destroy without doing it explicitly.

With one or two events across application, this works fine. 
But with more than 10 events registered in `EventService`, multiple components subscribing most of the events, I doubt is this a good solution?

What are my alternatives? At the least, an automatic unsubscribe for disposed of components will be a great help. Thank you.

Comment: One question, did you look at the angular reduxe version called ngrx? https://github.com/ngrx/platform